# How do I flag a title change?

Tags: support, edits, flags

One person changed the question I posted. I didn't even get to approve it.

My question was framed in such a way that I was looking to understand how things work, by citing an example.

The question was changed in such a way that it looked like I required the solution of only one particular scenario. More like a school kid who was given a question to be solved for homework.

Comment: Er. Why not simply edit the title back to what you believe it should be? What do you expect flagging to achieve (btw - you can flag the question once you have 15 reputation)?

Comment: There should be the original question there and then below it the modifications or interpretations of what the question could also mean. 
Then an option to flag the unwanted question as too misleading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I see three questions in your question:

> Is it normal that someone can edit my question without my having to approve it?

Yes. People with the full edit privilege can just edit. You get a chance to approve *suggested edits* but not full ones.

> What should I do if someone edits my question in a way I think is completely wrong?

You can rollback the edit to completely undo it, or you can make your own edit that undoes just some of what the editor did. You can also leave a comment, mentioning the editor with an @ followed by their user name, asking why they did that - they may have been trying to make it on topic for the site, for example. By conversing with the editor you may come to understand the motivation better.

> Should I use flagging whenever someone is wrong?

No, you should **flag** - a specific jargon word meaning clicking the "flag" link - only when someone is breaking the rules and a moderator needs to deal with it. Answers that are incorrect, edits that changed your intention, spelling mistakes, and many other "wrong" things are not for flagging. Even malicious rule breaking that can be corrected without a moderator may not need to be flagged - just fixing it is generally the better approach.

Comment: Cool. I'm new here I could use some advice like this. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your original title, what it was changed to, and what was in your question body, it is hard to advise whether the change seems reasonable.

However, when you say:

> The question was changed in such a way that it looked like I required
>   the solution  of only one particular scenario

it makes me think that someone may have tried to make your question more focussed.

Before rolling back I think you should consider whether someone may be helping to prevent your question from being closed as too broad.

Comment: My original title is 
`In Windows Batch file how to echo or rather Index the (n+1)th element in an array?`

The title someone changed it to is 
`how to echo the 1st,2nd,4th,5th,7th,8th,10th,11th element and so on.... of an array?`

Comment: @DannyBoi Raises hand! That was me. You **explicitly asked in the body of the question** "How do I modify the function so as to echo the following sequence,

    1st,2nd,4th,5th,7th,8th,10th,11th element and so on....
".  Apologies for the misunderstanding but next time you should should make sure the title and body of the question are in agreement and asking for the same thing.

Comment: @DannyBoi In addition, you modified the question after I had answered it saying you wanted a more generalised solution. Taking into account your comments I extended my answer **twice** to meet your changing requirements.